# not able record to record script on jmeter 5.1

Tags: jmeter

**Got this error while record script in jmeter 5.1**

[image]

1.Create thread

2.Thread group

3.HTTP(S)Test settings recorder
when going to do start getting this error showing in screenshot which is shown in the top left of the page.

Comment: Hello, any feedback on answer ? If it is ok you should accept it and upvote so that it's helpful to others. Thank you

Comment: I got an same issue, pop up is hanging on, and ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA crt file is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

I see no error in your screenshot.

When you start recorder, JMeter pops up a window that stays on top even when you're using browser allowing you to name each transaction.

Note that if you create all this manually, you must add a [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller) as a child of Thread Group as per this [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

Alternatively, use menu File > Templates > Recording which will do the setup for you.

If you want to learn more about JMeter and performance testing, this [book](https://leanpub.com/master-jmeter-from-load-test-to-devops) will help you.